# PHP (htaccess) rewrite with $_GET request

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made an simple framework for my website development.

I am currently using the this URL pattern:

```
www.example.com?r=account/login
```

But I would like to change it to:

```
www.example.com/account/login
```

remove `r=` from the URL.

I have seen YII framework does this. But I couldn't find a way to do this.

**Solution:** 
Add the code below to your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?r=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ index.php?r=$1
</IfModule>`
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are SEO friendly URLs which are quite common to use & implement. This is the `.htaccess` from a basic WordPress install which achieves a similar goal:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then in `index.php` you can test this by doing a variable dump of `$_GET` like so:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: If I add method above to `.htaccess` can I use, `$_GET['r']` to get page location? Or how do I get `'r'` in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I see you found a solution however you don't/shouldn't need two rewrite rules for the same thing just to add the `/`. You can use a `?` to make it optional. I also recommend using `[L]` on the rewrites so that it stops when the rule is met.

This is more of what you were looking for.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?r=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```